# Find $x-\frac{2x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{2x^9}{9}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find
$$S=x-\frac{2x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{2x^9}{9}+\frac{x^{11}}{11}+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{6n+1}}{6n+1}-\frac{2x^{6n+3}}{6n+3}+\frac{x^{6n+5}}{6n+5}$$

I could not find Regular pattern but I tried to differentiate $S$ as:
$$\frac{dS}{dx}=1-2x^2+x^4+x^6-2x^8+x^{10}+\cdots$$
any clue here?

Comment: What is the context for where this came from?  Without additional details there is nothing stopping the next term in the sequence that you didn't write to be $\frac{x^{12}}{\sqrt{\pi e}}$.  That is not to say that I would expect such a sequence with that as the next term to occur naturally, but from what we have seen we have no way of definitively knowing how often the extra factor of $-2$ occurs.  Does it occur specifically with exponents of $x$ a multiple of $3$?  Specifically at exponents of $x$ a power of $3$?

Answer (score 3):

$$M=\frac x1+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5+\frac{x^7}7+\frac{x^9}9+\frac{x^{11}}{11}+\cdots$$
is the Maclaurin series of $\tanh^{-1}x$ for $|x|<1$. The difference between this and $S$ is
$$M-S=\frac{3x^3}3+\frac{3x^9}9+\frac{3x^{15}}{15}+\dots$$
$$=\frac{(x^3)^1}1+\frac{(x^3)^3}3+\frac{(x^3)^5}5+\dots=\tanh^{-1}x^3$$
Thus
$$S=\tanh^{-1}x-\tanh^{-1}x^3,\ |x|<1$$